# Is there any better way of writing this test with Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a private method which is being called in a method I am testing.I want to verify the correct parameters are being passed to this private method. I have written the following setup in Moq which will test what I want, however it doesn't really allow me to follow the Arrange, Act, Assert pattern.

Is there any way I can perform a similar test where by the assert can appear with all of my other asserts? At the moment the code below lives within the Arrange.

```
     myClass.Setup(
                x =>
                x.myMethod(
                    It.IsAny<Person>>(),
                    It.IsAny<string>(),
                    It.IsAny<Person>(),
                    It.IsAny<ICollection<string>>(),
                    It.IsAny<ICollection<string>>(),
                    It.IsAny<bool>())).Callback
                <Person, string, Person, Person, ICollection<string>, bool>(
                    (a, b, c, d, e, f) =>
                        { 
                            Assert.AreEqual("NameA", a.Name); 
                            Assert.AreEqual("StringB", b);
                            Assert.AreEqual("NameC", c.Name);
                            Assert.AreEqual(2, d);

                            var dList = d.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Name);
                            Assert.AreEqual("PersonA", dList[0].Name)
                            Assert.AreEqual("PersonB", dList[1].Name);
                        });
```

I should say, I am aware that you can perfom a verify to check whether a method has been called with certain inputs, however I am not aware of any way of matching the ICollection params.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using those assertions to check the parameters, you can do it in your setup. If your mock uses strict behavior, it will fail if a parameter doesn't match the predicate.

```
 // declare your mock with strict behavior

 myClass.Setup(
     x =>
     x.myMethod(
         It.Is<Person>(person => person.Name == "NameA"),
         "Stringb",
         It.Is<Person>(person => person.Name == "NameC"),,
         It.Is<ICollection<string>>(coll =>{ 
                //your other validations
            }),
         It.IsAny<ICollection<string>>(),
         It.IsAny<bool>()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Purpose of unit tests is to verify that your class behaves as expected. You should exercise class via its public interface and check following things:

- class state changes
- returned results
- calls to dependencies

Other stuff has no value while class behaves as expected. You can refactor your class and make that private method in-line.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. You are correct, I shouldn't be testing the private methods. I made a mistake when writing up the example, it is actually a dependancy I was trying to test. The answer given by Ufuk helps in this instance.

Comment: @user460667 no problem, just advise for others not to test what shouldn't be tested :)